# enum error when compiling lms6suite from limemicro

Tags: c++, enums, compiler-errors

I just downloaded the Control Software for the lms6002 from lime Microsystem from https://github.com/limemicro/lms6suite
I tried to compile but I got an errors

```
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lms-suite.dir/gui_src/lms_suiteMain.cpp.o In file included from /usr/include/GL/glx.h:30:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/unix/glx11.h:13,
                 from /usr/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/gtk/glcanvas.h:14,
                 from /usr/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/glcanvas.h:192,
                 from /home/gabriel/ELSE/lms6suite/gui_src/fft/oglGraph/OpenGLGraph.h:15,
                 from /home/gabriel/ELSE/lms6suite/gui_src/fft/pnlFFTviewer.h:17,
                 from /home/gabriel/ELSE/lms6suite/gui_src/lms_suiteMain.cpp:32: /home/gabriel/ELSE/lms6suite/gui_src/pnlLMS6002USB.h:39:14: 
             error: expected identifier before ‘int’
         enum Status { SUCCESS, FAILURE };
              ^ In file included from /home/gabriel/ELSE/lms6suite/gui_src/lms_suiteMain.cpp:44:0: /home/gabriel/ELSE/lms6suite/gui_src/pnlLMS6002USB.h:39:21: 
             error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
         enum Status { SUCCESS, FAILURE };
                     ^ CMakeFiles/lms-suite.dir/build.make:1142: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/lms-suite.dir/gui_src/lms_suiteMain.cpp.o' failed make[2]:
*** [CMakeFiles/lms-suite.dir/gui_src/lms_suiteMain.cpp.o] Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/lms-suite.dir/all' failed make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/lms-suite.dir/all] Error 2 Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here the header file in question:

```
  1 #ifndef PNLLMS6002USBSTICK_H
  2 #define PNLLMS6002USBSTICK_H
  3 
  4 #include <wx/panel.h>
  5 class wxStaticText;
  6 class wxFlexGridSizer;
  7 class wxButton;
  8 
  9 #include "PluginPanel.h"
 10 class ConnectionManager;
 11 
 12 class pnlLMS6002USB: public wxPanel, public PluginPanel
 13 {
 14         public:
 15         pnlLMS6002USB(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize, int st    yle = 0, wxString name = "");
 16                 void Initialize( ConnectionManager *pControl);
 17         virtual ~pnlLMS6002USB();
 18         virtual void UpdatePanel();
 19 
 20                 wxButton* btnUpdateAll;
 21         wxComboBox* cmbVCXOcontrolVoltage;
 22 
 23         wxPanel* mPanelStreamPLL;
 24         wxTextCtrl* txtPllFreqRxMHz;
 25         wxStaticText* lblRealFreqTx;
 26         wxStaticText* lblRealFreqRx;
 27         wxTextCtrl* txtPllFreqTxMHz;
 28         wxTextCtrl* txtPhaseOffsetDeg;
 29         wxButton* btnConfigurePLL;
 30 
 31                 static const long ID_BUTTON_UPDATEALL;
 32         static const long ID_VCXOCV;
 33 
 34                 void OnbtnUpdateAll(wxCommandEvent& event);
 35         void ParameterChangeHandler(wxCommandEvent& event);
 36     protected:
 37         void OnConfigurePLL(wxCommandEvent &event);
 38 
 39         enum Status { SUCCESS, FAILURE };
 40 
 41         Status ConfigurePLL(ConnectionManager *serPort, const float fOutTx_MHz, const float fOutRx_MHz, const float phaseShift_deg);
 42 
 43         protected:
 44         ConnectionManager *m_serPort;
 45                 void BuildContent(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id,const wxPoint& pos,const wxSize& size);
 46 
 47                 DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
 48 };
 49 
 50 #endif
```

Step to reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/limemicro/lms6suite lms6suite
cd lms6suite
cd build
cmake ../
make
```

Can someone tell me where this comes from?

Tks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly due to the use of the word "Status" as the enum's name. That name causes a compiler error because Xlib.h, which is apparently included indirectly into the above program, contains the following line:

```
#define Status int
```

So after preprocessing, the definition is:

```
enum int { SUCCESS, FAILURE };
```

Which is not valid C++. Better rename that enum.